# What type of query is generated while resolving DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system

DNS resolution is in following steps:- Browser send a query to the resolver. (if not found in host file) Resolver checks its cache, and if record is not found, it forwards to root DNS server. Root DNS reply with the secondary Domain server and the process continues till name-server actually replies iP to the resolver and finally client. I want to know which type of the query (anycast, broadcast, unicast,anycast) generated in every processes.

Comment: Not quite exact. if you ask for www;,google.com and your resolver has no entry for this name in it's cache it will start looking for an entry for google.com if not it will look for com and if not it will ask root DNS. DNS requests are generally unicast requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a protocol called "Multicast DNS", which is used when there is no DNS Server available.

But in all other cases DNS queries are always unicast. This is why the Client needs the IP addresses of all DNS Servers he shall use, and a DNS Server needs the adresses of the forwarding servers. The traffic is directly pointed to the peer.